# How can remove header and footer from standard report in odoo 13

Tags: odoo-13

I try to add this code:

```
<template id="web_external_layout_iherited" 
      inherit_id="web.external_layout_standard" 
          customize_show="True" 
         name="Automatic Header">
  <xpath expr="//div[@class='header']" 
              position="replace">
      </xpath>
  </template>
```

but not work!!

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
<template id="web_external_layout_iherited"  inherit_id="web.external_layout_standard">
<xpath expr="//div[@t-attf-class='header o_company_#{company.id}_layout']" position="replace">
</xpath>
<xpath expr="//div[@t-attf-class='footer o_standard_footer o_company_#{company.id}_layout']" position="replace">
</xpath>
```

Comment: This remove header and footer for all reports. What if it was only one?

Answer (score 0):

If want to hide in specific report then pass one variable into the external layout template from report id as follows:

```
<template id="report_invoice_without_layout">
        <t t-call="web.html_container">
            <t t-foreach="docs" t-as="o">
                <t t-set="lang" t-value="o.partner_id.lang"/>
                <t t-set="print_with_payments" t-value="True"/>
                **<t t-set="hide_header_footer" t-value="True"/>**
                <t t-if="o._get_name_invoice_report() == 'l10n_gcc_invoice.arabic_english_invoice'" t-call="report_extension.arabic_english_invoice" t-lang="lang"/>
            </t>
        </t>
    </template>
```

And then add t-if condition in header and footer to hide as follows:

```
<template id="external_layout_standard" inherit_id="l10n_gcc_invoice.external_layout_standard">
    <xpath expr="//div[contains(@t-attf-class,'header')]" position="attributes">
            **<attribute name="t-if">not hide_header_footer</attribute>**
        </xpath>
        <xpath expr="//ul[hasclass('list-inline')]" position="attributes">
            **<attribute name="t-if">not hide_header_footer</attribute>**
        </xpath>
    </template>
```